# Reentry question for Americans to France legal rights

Tags: visa, resident-permit, france, us-citizens

I’ve been living in France for 3 years (all legal years) I have my *carte de séjour* and processed my renewal I am now just waiting for my new carte. While my old one has expired and my receipt also. After numerous times trying to obtain a new receipt with no luck. I have to travel back to the USA for short time. Can I reenter France just on a 90 days tourist visa?